How to Retrieve Organization Members in a GitHub Team Using Octokit and GitHub API?
I'm working on a project where I need to fetch the members of my organization who are assigned to specific teams using the GitHub API and Octokit library in my application. I've been digging through the Octokit documentation and GitHub API docs but haven't found a clear example or method for achieving this.
Can someone provide guidance or a code example on how to programmatically retrieve the members of my organization who are part of a particular team using Octokit and GitHub API? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
I've attempted to use the listMembers function provided by Octokit, but I'm struggling to find a way to filter the members by team.
